# Using Auto-Layout in Interface Builder/Storyboards to create a grid type layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am trying to create a grid type layout using Interface Builder/Storyboards. I am using a UIImageView as a background picture and placing UIButtons over the areas of the image that I want to be interactive. No matter what constraints I try I cannot seem to get the buttons to their proper spots. I have attached screen shots from Xcode 6, and well as provided a link to the project on GitHub. Thank you so much to anyone that can provide some insight.

**Edit**

After taking Matt's advice from the comments I created a layout using the images as the actual buttons. It works really well, but I can seem to get the buttons to constrain to each other  properly. I have attached a few images of what I'm getting now. If anyone has any idea what's going on that would be great! Also the GitHub Repository has been updated as well.

As a note, I am intentionally leaving the black bar at the bottom.

**View that I see on iPhone 4/4s**

[image]

Comment: Seems like a collection view would be a much simpler solution here

Comment: "placing UIButtons over the areas of the image" My suggestion is: don't. Let the buttons themselves _be_ the pieces of the image. That way you don't have to make the buttons figure out where the image behind them will be; they _contain_ the pieces of the image. All they have to be is positioned relative to _each other_, and that's easy.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll try and do that instead!

Comment: Matt, I tried creating the layout using only UIButtons, and it worked really well. The only problem is that the buttons appear too long for iPhone 4 and iPad but nothing else. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Follow the horizontal+vertical edge-to-edge definition principle

1. Each object must have an **edge-to-edge** constraint. i.e. *you must be able to virtually draw a line of constraints for any object to define it's edges.*
2. Rule #1 must be respected horizontally & vertically

As an example, and assuming you do not want your buttons to resize:

- pick an intrinsic width for each button
- align left-most margin of left-most button to container
- add an horizontal spacing constraint for each button to the one to the left
- assign a right-most margin of right-most button to container
- pick appropriate priorities

*Repeat vertically.*

Answer (score 1):

Please look into shared XIB.

You can achieve it via proportional to superview width or height constraint, +- constant for padding.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/AutolayoutExampleView.xib
[image]